# Trouble with old PHP code with latest PHP 5.4.11

Tags: php, regex

I used a PHP script over 9 years ago.

After updating PHP version to latest stable one (PHP 5.4.1.1), my script no longer works.

I found the problem area, Can anyone help me to convert this old PHP code to latest PHP 5.4.11.

```
if ((strlen($user_name)<$nick_min_length) or (strlen($user_name)>$nick_max_length)) {
    $error_text ="$w_incorrect_nick<br><a href=\"index.php\">$w_try_again</a>";
    include($file_path."designes/".$design."/error_page.php");
    exit;
}
if (ereg("[^".$nick_available_chars."]", $user_name)) {
    $error_text ="$w_incorrect_nick<br><a href=\"index.php\">$w_try_again</a>";
    include($file_path."designes/".$design."/error_page.php");
    exit;
}
if (strtolower($user_name) == strtolower(strip_tags($w_rob_name))) {
    $error_text ="$w_incorrect_nick<br><a href=\"index.php\">$w_try_again</a>";
    include($file_path."designes/".$design."/error_page.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: what error is PHP giving?

Comment: looking at your code the problem is with ereg since it was deprecated, try using other functions like preg_*

Comment: Could it be that [ereg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.3?

Comment: Looks like "give me teh codez" - Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (ereg("[^".$nick_available_chars."]", $user_name)) {
```

should be:

```
if (preg_match("/[^" . preg_quote($nick_available_chars) . "]/", $user_name)) {
```

`ereg()` is deprecated and should not be used. Also with [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you want to make sure special characters within your variable are properly escaped so you would use [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) and the regex would need [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), I put `/` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in `ereg` it is now deprecated may be removed in this version.

use `preg_match` instead of `ereg`